# Pickup Signal from a Wire - without a physical connection

Tags: amplifier, radio

**I am not an RF engineer and I don't even know if what I'm asking is possible.**

The idea is that the system will be outputting a 12V 10KHz signal onto the wire with one end connected (Wire Under Test) - and I would like this signal to be detected by another wire that is wrapped onto this wire but not connected electrically.

This is for a quality test system and for quality reasons, I cannot connect the Wire Under Test's other end electrically anywhere.

If I output a 5V 10KHz signal via my function-gen onto this wire (with only 1 connected to the function-gen) and put the tip of my oscilloscope probe onto the PVC insulation, I am able to pick up a 200 mV 10KHz signal very easily.

If I further wrap another wire onto the wire under test and put my oscilloscope on that wire, the signal jumps to 1V 10 KHz.

How can I design a circuit that lets my amplify the signal from the wrapped wire? In my naiveness, I tried and connected a LM324 based Inverting amplifier but I received no input - until I connected the probe of my oscilloscope at the input!

Answer (score 3):

With a capacitive pickup from a short length of wire running along (parallel to, or wrapped around) your "wire under test," you're going to receive a (very) high-impedance signal pickup.

In order to get good amplification of this high-impedance signal, you're going to need to use a higher input impedance amplifier.

Here's a diagram of one such amp (using a J211 JFET transistor) I was working on for another question (modified for your 10khz source frequency):
[image: High input impedance amplifier]

Comment: What's the purpose of the LC Tank? Will this circuit work with a MOSFET?

Comment: @Saad The LC tank narrows the bandwidth of frequencies that get amplified. If desired, it could be removed, but the 100ohm resistor would need to be raised to a few Kohms. -- This circuit could work with a mosfet, but would likely need to be re-biased &/or have several resistor values changed, to fit the electrical characteristics of the new transistor.

Comment: Do you think a 2 Meg ohm resistor from gate to ground might be required, to stabilize the bias on the JFET ?

Comment: @Marla Thank you for pointing out that I had protected the antenna from ESD buildup with my 3M resistor (accidentally, but useful), rather than my intent of having it bias the gate. I have updated my diagram to correct the error.

Answer (score 2):

> I am not an RF engineer and I don't even know if what I'm asking is possible.

Why do you think its not possible if you already did exactly that - "Pickup Signal from a Wire - without a physical connection " with your oscilloscope?

> If I output a 5V 10KHz signal via my function-gen onto this wire (with only 1 connected to the function-gen) and put the tip of my oscilloscope probe onto the PVC insulation, I am able to pick up a 200 mV 10KHz signal very easily.
>
> If I further wrap another wire onto the wire under test and put my oscilloscope on that wire, the signal jumps to 1V 10 KHz.

The wire you are probing and the wire that its wrapped around are capacitively coupled to each other. The smaller the distance between the wires and the longer the distance they run in parallel (the larger the area between them), the bigger the parasitic coupling. Electric field coupling is also proportional to the frequency.

> How can I design a circuit that lets my amplify the signal from the wrapped wire? In my naiveness, I tried and connected a LM324 based Inverting amplifier but I received no input - until I connected the probe of my oscilloscope at the input!

The electric field causes minor movement of charge carriers in the wire you measure, or in other words - a very low current.
To measure this phenomenon, you need a very high impedance input (you oscilloscope probe) because a small current induced on a high impedance circuit results in a higher voltage.